# Lvalue required as left operand of assignment

Tags: iphone, objective-c, properties

Hello I get the "Lvalue required as left operand of assignment" error in xcode. Why?
Here is my code (window1/2 are UIViewController) :

```
- (void)loadView
{

    UIScrollView *scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,460)];
    UIView *contentView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,640,460)];


    self.window1 = [TweetViewController alloc];
    self.window2 = [InfoViewController alloc];


    [contentView addSubview:self.window1.view];
    self.window2.view.frame.origin.x = 320; //HERE IS THE ERROR!!
    [contentView addSubview:self.window2.view];


    [scrollView addSubview:contentView];
    scrollView.contentSize = contentView.frame.size;


    scrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;


    self.view = scrollView;


    [contentView release];
    [scrollView release];
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The part `self.window2.view.frame` will leave you with a getter, not actually reaching into and *grabbing* the internal frame `CGRect`. What you need to do is get the `CGRect` change it and then set it back into the view.

```
CGRect f = self.window2.view.frame; // calls the getter
f.origin.x = 320;
self.window2.view.frame = f; // calls the setter
```

Comment: doesn't he need to initialize the Tweet and Info view controllers as well?

Comment: @ennuikiller True, but that is another problem. I'm only answering about the Lvalue problem

Answer (score 2):

You have to set the frame as a whole:

```
CGRect f = self.window2.view.frame;
f.origin.x = 320;

self.window2.view.frame = f;
```

See [properties](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocProperties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH17-SW1).

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of advanced (or *experimental*...); you should understand this problem, and do it the regular way (à la [epatel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1998580/45813)) a bunch until you have it **cold**.

But I have a [macro](https://github.com/claybridges/libvarobjc) that lets you do this

```
    @morph(self.window2.view.frame, _.origin.x = 320);
    [contentView addSubview:self.window2.view];
```